# Want to implode a list along with some html tags

Tags: php

I have this php function in my tumblr api powered website which generates a list of tags in format

```
[ Tag1,Tag2,Tag3 ]
```

I want to make it output tags in this format instead

```
[<b class="tagsingle">Tag1</b>,<b class="tagsingle">Tag2</b>,<b class="tagsingle">Tag3</b>]
```

Here is the implode php line and another line that prints the list of tags.

```
$tags = ($row->tumblr_tag != NULL)? $row->tumblr_tag : implode(',&nbsp ',$post->tags);
echo '<p class="tags">'.$tags.'</p></div>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's exactly your problem?

Comment: i have updated the question, please take a look, when i posted the question first time, the html tags got auto removed due to improper formating. my mistake

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#111700 look at this example. if you have issues, post what you tried and people will help you more

Comment: atleast post what is your expected and current result, so that other can identify your problem.

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper : i did just that, but due to improper formating, html tags got auto removed, sorry, my mistake. I have updated the question, please check

Comment: @JqueryNoob I provided an answer. Hope I can help you.

Comment: `echo vsprintf(str_repeat('<b class="tagsingle">%s</b>', count($tags)), $tags);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$tagsString = implode('</b>, <b class="tagsingle">',$post->tags);
echo '<p class="tags"><b class="tagsingle">'.$tagsString.'</b></p>';
```

This should result in:

```
<p class="tags">
    <b class="tagsingle">Tag1</b>
    <b class="tagsingle">Tag2</b>
    ...
</p>
```

Comment: When i use "$tagsString" it shows a white screen, but when i use "$tags" it works but gives wrong output ie `<p class="tags"><b class="tagsingle">tagone,tagtwo,tagthree</b></p>` here is the full code for reference http://pastebin.com/UyyUkzXn, tags part is on line 1265 and 1282

Comment: @JqueryNoob I edited my post. I wrongly used `$tags` in the `echo` string

Comment: i updated the code, but Its still outputing like this http://image.prntscr.com/image/c60515c3f34244c7bff2a64ce1f2056b.png

Comment: @JqueryNoob Maybe you should try to left out the space like this: `implode('</b>,<b class="tagsingle">',$post->tags);`

Comment: I think these single quotes are conflicting with my code, when i remove them my page works, but when i keep them it shows a blank screen [']<p class="tags"><b class="tagsingle">'.$tagsString.'</b></p>['] , there is already a single quote in use at beginning of "<p>" tag http://prntscr.com/ddzvgg

Comment: @JqueryNoob Then you left this out and you're fine. Upvote my answer, if it is useful

Comment: but unfortunately the problem is still not resolved, its still outputting : http://image.prntscr.com/image/9dc404bb20804ef49789319632942c01.png, really sorry to bother you so much :P but it seems we are too close to a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129523/discussion-between-rbr94-and-jquery-noob).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you want to explode, not implode.

```
explode(',&nbsp ',$post->tags)
```

Edit 1:

Then you will get an array of tags, wich can be processed like:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
     echo '<b>'.$tag.'</b>';
 }
```

And so on.

Comment: Hello, actually what i want to do is output tags in this format `<b class="tagsingle">Tag1</b>,<b class="tagsingle">Tag2</b>,<b class="tagsingle">Tag3</b>` but i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: thanks for the update, i really appreciate your help. btw can you please tell me how i can use this part `foreach ($tags as $tag){print '<b>'.$tag.'</b>';}` inside of an echo tag? cause in my code tags are being populated inside of an echo tag. here is the full code for reference pastebin.com/UyyUkzXn, tags part is on line 1265 and 1282

Comment: @JqueryNoob the print function in php is an alias of the echo function. I edited to make it clear for you.